# Derivatives of first/second order going to zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a smooth function such that $F(0)=F(h_1)=F(h_2)=0$ for some $h_1,h_2$ fixed ($F$ depends of $h_1,h_2$).

I also have that $F'(0)=a,F''(0)=b$.

> I need to prove that if $h_1,h_2\rightarrow 0$, so $a,b\rightarrow 0$.

Well, $a=0$ by the Mean Value Theorem, because there's $c\in [0,h_1]$ s.t. $F'(c)=0$. As $h_1\rightarrow 0, c\rightarrow 0$ and $F'(c)\rightarrow a$. So, $a\rightarrow 0$.

Is it OK?

But what about the second derivative?

Many thanks!

Comment: tag mean-curvature-flows doesn't necessarily have much to do with Mean Value Theorem

Comment: Thanks, I retagged to limits, I do not know if this is better...

Comment: there is tag calculus

Comment: How do you know $F'(c) \to a$? Do you assume continuity of $F'$?

Comment: Yes, @kccu, it is smooth.

Comment: Many thanks, @Mirko

Comment: you are welcome, I didn't do much, glad someone answered your question and you accepted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch:

Suppose wlog that $h_1<h_2$.  Then, by the mean value theorem, there is some $d$ in $(h_1,h_2)$ such that $F'(d)=0$.  Then, by the mean value theorem, there exists some $e$ in $(c,d)$ such that $(F')'(e)=0$.  Now, use your original argument.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I could get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove it, because it is not true.

Consider the function $\sin(\frac{x}{h_1h_2})$, the derivative is $\frac{1}{h_1h_2}\cos(\frac{x}{h_1h_2})$, and it has no limit when $(h_1,h_2) \to 0$.

You need stronger hypothesis such as equicontinousness.